# Blackberry Development-eclipse plugin

Tags: blackberry

I want to use JAVA SE Color class in my Blackberry application.

From `java.awt.Color package`

I have a project on image effect and control(hue,contrast).I have seen android code in that they use Color.colorToHSV().
I saw the same for Blackberry Color class but it has no methods.
So thats why i need JAVA SE color class so that i can use these methods,....

Can I use JAVA SE Color class?
What should I do to do so?

Comment: please give detail what you want to do.

Comment: Why do you want to use Color from that specific package ? cant you use hexadecimal code for Color Implementation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Java SE Color class support in BlackBerry SDK.

Instead of this class there is `net.rim.device.api.ui.Color` class. It is less functional than Java SE `java.awt.Color` class.

But there's a workaround.

When you have installed Java SE SDK on your computer, then in that folder where Java SE SDK installed there is `src.zip` file.

This file contains source code for all standard Java SE classes, including `java.awt.Color` class. Unpack this `src.zip` file, find `java/awt/Color.java` and inspect it, how does it work.

And implement this functionality for your BB application.

Comment: thanks Rafael for your Reply.I used the methods of color class i.e RGBToHSB() and HSBToRGB().It works well(not as good as I wanted).